# invalid Directory name used in property "CurrentDirectory" vbscript

Tags: vbscript, directory

I'm trying to compile au3 script through vbscript which located in another directory, so I used "CurrentDirectory" property to change the working directory from script directory to au3 file directory using this code

```
drivepath = "K"
strTempTarget = "New Folder"
filename = "gate.jpg"
IconName = "102.ico"

Comm = "cmd /c " & "Aut2Exe.exe /in " & filename & ".au3" & " /out "  & filename & ".exe" & " /icon " & IconName
Path = """" & drivepath & "\" & strTempTarget & """"
MsgBox(Path)

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.CurrentDirectory = Path
objShell.Run(Comm), 0, True
```

But I got an error "invalid file name or directory name"
since there is an empty space in "strTempTarget" value I should put a double quotes at the start and at the end of directory name "Path" I even tried to use ASCII : something like

```
Path = Chr(34) & drivepath & "\" & strTempTarget & Chr(34)
```

but the same error keep raising
So how to make this script work fine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell needs quoted pathes, because it uses space as separator; .CurrentDirectory 'knows' the whole string (included any spaces) is meant to be a folder path; so don't quote the string for .CurrentDirectory.

Evidence:

```
>> Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
>> Path = """C:\Documents and Settings"""
>> objShell.CurrentDirectory = Path
>>
Error Number:       -2147024773
Error Description:
>> Path = "C:\Documents and Settings"
>> objShell.CurrentDirectory = Path
>>
>> <-- no news are good news
```